# Pandas modified Dataframe index change

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have the following codes. I would like to know if the modified dataframe can be started from 0,1,2... so on like regular indexing on Panda.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([4, 4, 3, 4, 1])
df2 = df[2:4]
```

where df2 is now-

```
     0
0    3
2    3
```

If I would like to access df2 in some regular indexing convention from 0..n, I can't with this approach. Is there some other way that can be done?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `df2 = df2.reset_index()`

Comment: In my opinion need select by position e.g. `print (df2.iloc[[0]])`

Comment: @jezrael, i don't think this is a duplicate of the post you linked to. it seems the OP needs guidance on how to use `reset_index`

Comment: @HaleemurAli - If yes, was added dupe for `.reset_index()` too.

Comment: @HaleemurAli - Both solutions working, but if use `iloc` for select `reset_index` is not necessary.

Answer (score 2):

You can reset the index using [`reset_index()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df2 = df2.reset_index(drop=True)
```

For your data, this prints:

```
>>> print(df2.reset_index(drop=True))
   0
0  3
1  4
```